# How should I represent hierarchical flag enums?

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I have the following set of enums:

```
[Flags]
public enum Categories : uint
{
    A = (1 << 0),
    B = (1 << 1),
    B1 = B | (1 << 16),
    B2 = B | (1 << 17),
    B3 = B | (1 << 18),
    B4 = B | (1 << 19),
    B5 = B | (1 << 20),
    C = (1 << 2),
    C1 = C | (1 << 21),
    D = (1 << 3),
    D1 = D | (1 << 22),
    D2 = D | (1 << 23),
    E = (1 << 4),
    F = (1 << 5),
    F1 = F | (1 << 23),
    F2 = F | (1 << 24),
    F3 = F | (1 << 25),
    F4 = F | (1 << 26),
    F5 = F | (1 << 27),
    G = (1 << 6),
    H = (1 << 7),
    H1 = H | (1 << 28),
}
```

The idea is that the enums represent a hierarchical structure where a child enum implies its parent and any number of flags can be applied.

The problem I am seeing is that all child enums are not being represented during debugging as names or sets of names. I.E., `Categories.F` = "F" but `Categories.F2` = 16777248. I would have hoped `Categories.F2` = "F, F2" or at least "F2"

How can I make my enums remain recognized as flags? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I just compiled and ran your code, I got `Categories.F2.ToString() = "F2"`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, sorry - it's actually only a problem in debugging watch windows, etc. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: So the problem is only during debugging? I wonder if you add `[DebugerDisplay("{ToString()}")]` does that have any effect?

Comment: Problem can be reproduced if you have any flags enum where one composite enum constant consists of a named bit and an unnamed one. Example: `[Flags] enum Categories { F = 1, F2 = 1 | 2, }`. A value of `Categories` with underlying numeric value `3`, will be shown as `"3"` by the debugger, whereas `.ToString()` and `.ToString("F")` both give `"F2"`. It seems like a ***bug***.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Adding `[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]` attribute (while keeping `[Flags]` of course) works (`using System.Diagnostics` namespace). Then the debugger shows the same as `ToString()`. But is's strange that it is necessary. Why does the debugger have a different algorithm than `ToString()` by default?

Comment: @DanRasmussen thanks, I've included some detail about `DebuggerDisplay` and `DebuggerTypeProxy` in my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

It's very strange that the value in the debugger is different from the `ToString` value. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx), the two should match (because the `Enum` type does indeed override `ToString`).

> If a C# object has an overridden `ToString()`, the debugger will call the override and show its result instead of the standard `{<typeName>}`.

Obviously this is not working for enums. My best guess is that the debugger is trying to do some special, undocumented handling of enum types. Adding the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) apparently resolves the issue by overriding this behavior.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
[Flags]
public enum Categories : uint
{
    ...
}
```

---

> Categories.F2.ToString() = "F, F2"

C# won't do that magic for you, because `F2` already has it's own name in the enum. You can manually mark the the individual members like this:

```
public enum Categories
{
    [Description("F, F2")]
    F2 = F | (1 << 24),
}
```

And then write code to convert to the description.

```
public static string ToDescription(this Categories c)
{
    var field = typeof(Categories).GetField(c.ToString());
    if (field != null)
    {
        return field.GetCustomAttributes().Cast<DescriptionAttribute>().First().Description;
    }
}
...
Categories.F2.ToDescription() == "F, F2";
```

Or you could do a bit of magic to generate this yourself:

```
public static string ToDescription(this Categories c)
{
    var categoryNames =
        from v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)).Cast<Category>()
        where v & c == c
        orderby v
        select v.ToString();
    return String.Join(", ", categoryNames);
}
```

Unfortunately, an extension method cannot be used with `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`, but you can use [`DebuggerTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute.aspx), YMMV but you could try this:

```
[DebuggerType("CategoryDebugView")]
[Flags]
public enum Categories : uint
{
    ...
}

internal class CategoryDebugView
{
    private Category value;

    public CategoryDebugView(Category value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var categoryNames =
            from v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)).Cast<Category>()
            where v & c == c
            orderby v
            select v.ToString();
        return String.Join(", ", categoryNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: [DebuggerType] does not exist. [DebuggerTypeProxy] exists but cannot be applied to enums:  "error CS0592: Attribute 'DebuggerTypeProxy' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'assembly, class, struct' declarations."

Comment: @robert4 my mistake, I was referring to `DebuggerTypeProxy`. I'll double-check this answer when I get to a computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you ask with a little work. I've created some extension methods on `Categories` which use `HasFlag()` to detemine whether the enum value has a particular parent and then calls `ToString()` on them and concatenates the result.

```
public static class CategoriesExtensionMethods
{
    public static Categories GetParentCategory(this Categories category)
    {
        Categories[] parents = 
        {
            Categories.A,
            Categories.B,
            Categories.C,
            Categories.D,
            Categories.E,
            Categories.F,
            Categories.G,
            Categories.H,
        };

        Categories? parent = parents.SingleOrDefault(e => category.HasFlag(e));
        if (parent != null)
            return (Categories)parent;
        return Categories.None;
    }

    public static string ToStringWithParent(this Categories category)
    {
        var parent = GetParentCategory(category);
        if (parent == Categories.None)
            return category.ToString();
        return string.Format("{0} | {1}", parent.ToString(), category.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
var f1 = Categories.F1;

var f1ParentString = f1.ToStringWithParent();
// f1ParentString = "F | F1"

var f = Categories.F;
var fParentString = f.GetParentCategory();
// fParentString = "F"
```

### Update

Here is a more handsome way to go about implementing `GetParentCategory()` if you don't want to specify all of your parents.

```
public static Categories GetParentCategory(this Categories category)
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)).Cast<Categories>();
    var parent = values.SingleOrDefault(e => category.HasFlag(e) && e != Categories.None && category != e);
    if (parent != Categories.None)
        return (Categories)parent;
    return Categories.None;
}
```